# How to get date in a specific timezone?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

greetings all
i am using the following method to get the current time in GMT timezone

```
public static Timestamp getCurrentTimeGMT() {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        long time = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(time);
        return new Timestamp(time - offset);

    }
```

but when i try to use the same method with minor changes to get the current time in GMT+3
it gives me the same result of GMT ? i don't know why:

```
public static Timestamp getCurrentTimeGMT3() {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
    long time = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(time);
    return new Timestamp(time - offset);

}
```

any ideas why the above code doesn't work properly, and how to do such a method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Timestamp` extends `Date` - it doesn't *have* a time zone, conceptually. It just represents an instant in time.

If you want to display it in a particular calendar with a particular time zone, that's a formatting issue. Create the appropriate calendar with the relevant time zone, and set the timestamp within it accordingly.

(As per normal, I'd like to recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in API where possible. It's much cleaner.)

Comment: ...and has the concept of a LocalDateTime.

Comment: can you tell me how to do such a behaviour using joda time ?

Comment: @sword101: What behaviour *exactly*? If you just want an instant representing the current time (with no associated time zone) use `new Instant()`. If you want the current time and an associate with UTC, use `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.Utc)`.

Comment: i just want to get current time in the timezone (GMT+3)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you subtract the offset from the time in the last line? That is basically resetting your time back to GMT. You retrieve GMT+3 then you subtract 3 hours from that.

Comment: He is subtracting the offset of the default time zone, not the time zone he used to create the Calendar with.

Answer (score 2):

What Jon said. A Timestamp does not have a time zone, it's always UTC, and really shouldn't be abused for representing local time. If you really need objects to represent local time, Joda Time [has a class for that](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html).

And you should be aware that "GMT+3" is not a real valid time zone. A time zone has not just a base offset, but also a daylight savings time offset, which can be different for time zones with the same base offset, and can even change for the same time zone due to legislation. A real time zone ID is "Europe/Berlin" or "Australia/Darwin".

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API and since then it is strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** The first important thing to understand is the difference between a ***timezone*** and a ***timezone offset***.

A ***timezone*** is identified by an ID, typically in the form of a Region/City e.g. Europe/London. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you can check a list of tz database time zones. The `java.time` API provides with [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to represent a date-time with timezone.

A ***timezone offset*** tells us the amount of time by which the time of a place is offset from the UTC e.g. 2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 which tells us that this date-time is offset by `01:00` hours from UTC i.e. we need to subtract `01:00` hours to get the equivalent date-time at UTC. The `java.time` API provides with [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to represent a date-time with time zone offset.

Some time zones observe [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) i.e. America/New_York observes an offset of `-05:00` hours in the winter while `-04:00` hours in the summer.[Here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york) you can check an illustration.

A `ZonedDateTime` automatically reflects the applicable offset while we create an `OffsetDateTime` with a fixed offset value. Thus, `GMT` and `GMT+3` mentioned in your question are not time zones, they represent time zone offset. A better and more modern way to write it is `Z` and `+03:00` respectively.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        // Current date-time in America/New_York
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(zone));

        // A sample winter date-time in America/New_York
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2023, 01, 14), LocalTime.of(10, 20, 30), zone));

        // A sample summer date-time in America/New_York
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2023, 06, 14), LocalTime.of(10, 20, 30), zone));

        // Current OffsetDateTime with an offset of 00:00 hours (UTC time)
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));

        // Current OffsetDateTime with an offset of 05:30 hours
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.of("+05:30"));
        System.out.println(odt);
        // The same OffsetDateTime converted to UTC time (will be 05:30 less)
        System.out.println(odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    }
}
```

**Output from a sample run:**

```
2023-01-14T12:40:04.348474-05:00[America/New_York]
2023-01-14T10:20:30-05:00[America/New_York]
2023-06-14T10:20:30-04:00[America/New_York]
2023-01-14T17:40:04.352982Z
2023-01-14T23:10:04.353969+05:30
2023-01-14T17:40:04.353969Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/yQGT30)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Code to get Time in Different Time Zone

```
public class GetZoneDateTime {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String reqTzId = "Asia/Singapore";

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("Local Now: " + now + " TimeZone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());

    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(reqTzId);
    System.out.println("Req TimeZone : " + zoneId);

    LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now(zoneId);
    System.out.println("tzLocalDateTime: " + localNow);

    ZonedDateTime zoneNow = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
    System.out.println("tzZonedDateTime: " + zoneNow);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`c.getTimeInMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970 0:00 UTC and will return the same value, no matter which time zone is used in the Calendar instance.

If you create a Calendar with a time zone and need access to the time fields, you should access these directly:

```
int h = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int m = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int s = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Timezone static method.

```
TimeZone default = TimeZone.getDefault();

TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+3"));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
Date date = cal.getTime(); // converted date time
System.out.println(date.toString());

// Set Back to System Default
TimeZone.setDefault(default);
```